# timeout while nodejs API call

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, timeout

i have built a nodejs-API, everything works fine, but in one of my controller functions, the response is sometimes not sent (in time). In these cases everything works fine too, just don´t get the response to frontend (in time). There the console shows:

> Error: timeout of 1000ms exceeded
> at createError (createError.js:16)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleTimeout (xhr.js:96)

my controller function:

```
 exports.postQuestion = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (!req.userId) {
      const error = new Error("Authorization failed!");
      error.msg = "No valid token!";
      error.statusCode = 401;
      throw error;
    }
    const user = await User.findById(req.userId);

    if (user.role === "newUser") {
      const error = new Error("No Permission!");
      error.msg = "User is not permitted!";
      error.statusCode = 401;
      throw error;
    }

    const category = await Category.findOne({ value: req.body.category });

    if (!category) {
      const error = new Error("Unknown category!");
      error.msg = "Can´t find this category in database!";
      error.statusCode = 404;
      throw error;
    }

    const parsedAnswers = JSON.parse(req.body.answers);
    const fileUrl = req.file ? req.file.path.replace(/\\/g, "/") : "";

    const resp = await deepl({
      text: req.body.title,
      target_lang: "EN",
      auth_key: deeplAuthKey,
    });

    const lang = resp.data.translations[0].detected_source_language;

    const answersArray = parsedAnswers.map((obj) => obj.answer);
    const stringArray = answersArray.map((answer) => answer);
    const urlString = stringArray.join("/");

    const ta = await deepl({
      text: urlString,
      target_lang: lang === "DE" ? "EN" : "DE",
      auth_key: deeplAuthKey,
    });

    const challenge = new Challenge();

    if (lang === "DE") {
      challenge.deAnswers = parsedAnswers;
    }
    if (lang === "EN") {
      challenge.enAnswers = parsedAnswers;
    }

    const tt = await deepl({
      text: req.body.title,
      target_lang: lang === "DE" ? "EN" : "DE",
      auth_key: deeplAuthKey,
    });
    const tb = await deepl({
      text: req.body.body,
      target_lang: lang === "DE" ? "EN" : "DE",
      auth_key: deeplAuthKey,
    });

    const translated = ta.data.translations[0].text;
    const transTitle = tt.data.translations[0].text;
    const transBody = tb.data.translations[0].text;
    const transAns = translated.split("/");
    const transAnswers = [...parsedAnswers];
    for (let i = 0; i < parsedAnswers.length; i++) {
      transAnswers[i].answer = transAns[i];
    }

    challenge.type = req.body.type;
    challenge.category = category._id;
    challenge.image = fileUrl;
    challenge.userRole = user.role;
    challenge.user = user._id;
    challenge.public = false;

    if (lang === "DE") {
      challenge.deTitle = req.body.title;
      challenge.deBody = req.body.body;
      challenge.enAnswers = transAnswers;
      challenge.enTitle = transTitle;
      challenge.enBody = transBody;
    }
    if (lang === "EN") {
      challenge.enTitle = req.body.title;
      challenge.enBody = req.body.body;
      challenge.deAnswers = transAnswers;
      challenge.deTitle = transTitle;
      challenge.deBody = transBody;
    }

    const newChallenge = await challenge.save();

    console.log(newChallenge);

    res.status(200).json({ challenge: newChallenge });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("ERROR", err);
    next(err);
  }
};
```

I have some async requests there, so of course it can take a little longer, but is there a way to set more time for timeout or is there any other solution? The data is always stored in database. (sometimes the response is received correct)

Thanks in advance.

Sven

Comment: Try increasing the timeout on the front-end, since the front-end is responsible for timing out the request.

Comment: I would like to do this, but how?

Comment: I am using axios for the request, but axios by default doesn´t have a timeout set. Even if i set a timeout to axios, nothing change. Its always this timeout after 1000ms.

Comment: ooouupps, sorry found my mistake. I forgot, that i defined a timeout in my axios instance....